# How do I listen on port 443 using Express?

Tags: node.js, express, https

```
var app, certificate, credentials, express, fs, http, httpServer, https, httpsServer, privateKey;

fs = require('fs');

http = require('http');

https = require('https');

privateKey = fs.readFileSync('key.pem', 'utf8');

console.log(privateKey);

certificate = fs.readFileSync('cert.pem', 'utf8');

console.log(certificate);

credentials = {
  key: privateKey,
  cert: certificate
};

express = require('express');

app = express();

httpServer = http.createServer(app);

httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpServer.listen(80);

httpsServer.listen(443);
```

I am on OS X and I have confirmed nothing else is listening on 80 and 443. I run this as `sudo` and when I go `http://127.0.0.1`, it works. However, when I go to `https://127.0.0.1`, I get not found.

What am I doing incorrect?

Comment: Do you literally get a 404 not found response on the https URL? That indicates that there actually is a server listening. OTOH, if you got a connection refused, it means no server is listening.

Comment: I get Connection failed. Not a 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following line of code:

```
app.listen(443);
```

Also, try getting rid of all of the http module, as express handles most of that for you. Look at the beginning Hello World for Express, http://expressjs.com/starter/hello-world.html and look for the part where it handles the port.

Comment: Still get connection failure

Answer (score 10):

To enable your app to listen for both `http` and `https` on ports `80` and `443` respectively, do the following

Create an express app:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

The app returned by `express()` is a JavaScript function. It can be be passed to Node’s HTTP servers as a callback to handle requests. This makes it easy to provide both HTTP and HTTPS versions of your app using the same code base.

You can do so as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/cert.pem')
};

http.createServer(app).listen(80);
https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
```

For complete detail see the [doc](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html)